# javascript - Convert array to string while preserving brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
var myArray =[[1,2,3,4,5], 
              [1,2,3,4,5], 
              [1,2,3,4,5], 
              [1,2,3,4,5]];
```

I wish to put its contents in a div (so that one can easily copy and paste).

However, when I do

```
var x = document.getElementById("result");
x.textContent = myArray;
```

I just get

```
1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(myArray)` Did you want it formatted exactly like the original?

Comment: Thanks, formatting was a non-issue, but it's good to know (as you mention below) how to do so if it was

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var x = document.getElementById("result");
x.textContent = JSON.stringify( myArray );
```

Answer (score 11):

You can either use `JSON.stringify` or custom joining like this

```
console.log("[[" + myArray.join("],[") + "]]");
# [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
# [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

Comment: +1 This would be the way to go if he wanted it to be formatted just like the original syntax. Would just need to add a `\n` and a space. Probably faster too.