# How to get the real console.log formatted output

Tags: javascript

I tried solution suggested here [How to get the console.log content as string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052775/how-to-get-the-console-log-content-as-string-in-javascript)

Problem is it's missing the full formatted output : it gives a, b, c instead whereas I'd like to get ["a", "b", "c"] for my case
https://jsfiddle.net/eywjn9o8/

```
var logBackup = console.log;
var logMessages = [];

console.log = function() {
    logMessages.push.apply(logMessages, arguments);
    logBackup.apply(console, arguments);
};

const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(Object.keys(object1));
alert(logMessages)
```

[image]

Comment: You're alerting the array, which calls `toString()` on it implicitly. Certainly not what you're looking for. Use `logBackup(logMessages);` instead and it'll be closer to the actual console output. Or use `alert(JSON.stringify(logMessages[0]))`

Comment: @ChrisG post it as answer?

Comment: @Cid Certainly not

Comment: Duplicate: [JavaScript print array to string with brackets and quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956228/javascript-print-array-to-string-with-brackets-and-quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox and Google Chrome now have a built-in `JSON` object, so you can just say `alert(JSON.stringify(logMessages))`. This is not part of the Javascript language spec, so you shouldn't rely on the `JSON` object being present in all browsers, but for debugging purposes it's incredibly useful.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3006688/12014952)