# how can I convert my json string to a specific format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json string:

```
arguments[0] = [{"one":"1","two":"1","three":"15","four":"esj","five":null,"six":"2015-10-15 00:00:00","seven":null},
{"one":"1","two":"1","three":"15","four":"esj","five":null,"six":"2015-10-15 00:00:00","seven":null},
{"one":"1","two":"1","three":"15","four":"esj","five":null,"six":"2015-10-15 00:00:00","seven":null, ...}]
```

and I want to change it to the format like this:

```
[ '1', '1', '15', 'esj', null, '2015-10-15 00:00:00', null],
[ '1', '1', '15', 'esj', null, '2015-10-15 00:00:00', null],
[ '1', '1', '15', 'esj', null, '2015-10-15 00:00:00', null], etc...
```

how can I do it in jquery?

EDIT:

Using @Joseph the dreamer's answer I almost made it work, now I'm using:

```
return ["['"+arg.one+"'", "'"+arg.two+"'", "'"+arg.three+"'", "'"+arg.four+"'", "'"+arg.five+"'", "'"+arg.six+"']"]
```

and it produces me this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6], etc
```

which is fine, but I need to convert it later on to a string. How can I do that?

Comment: Use a basic `for` loop and build it yourself.

Comment: @Blazemonger can you tell me how to do it exactly?

Comment: Your question is confusing. [First you ask _only_ to convert _json (or objects) to arrays_](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33223848/revisions)  and now you've amended your question to further ask how to convert it to strings (which could be another question, [which would be a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746353/javascript-convert-array-to-string-while-preserving-brackets/22746363#22746363)). Actually at the first revision your question was clear and well formatted to be useful (to get an upvote). Now it's ... confusing. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No jQuery required actually. All you need is `map`.

```
var arr = arguments[0].map(function(arg){
  return [arg.one, arg.two, arg.three, arg.four, arg.five, arg.six, arg.seven];
});
```

Would have gone for `Object.keys` to loop through the keys, but order had to be preserved. Plus, I would discourage modifying `arguments`.

Comment: thanks, I used your answer and I'm almost there, but I have one additional question - can you check my update to the main question?

Comment: @user3766930 `JSON.stringify()`