# How to make javascript turn a multidimensional array into a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in javascript that I would like to be able to turn into a string while preserving brackets. I have taken a look at other questions such as [javascript - Convert array to string while preserving brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746353/javascript-convert-array-to-string-while-preserving-brackets) and the answers there didn't help me much.

My array could look like the following:

```
[[[0,0,1],1],[[1,0,0],4],[[1,0,1],5], [[0,1,1],3],[[1,1,0],6],[[0,1,0],2]]
```

When I print the array I see:

```
0,0,1,1,1,0,0,4,1,0,1,5,0,1,1,3,1,1,0,6,0,1,0,2
```

The output that I am expecting is what the original array looks like.

I have also tried the following code:

```
alert("[[" + myArray.join("],[") + "]]");
```

This works for almost everything, I get an output of:

```
[[0,0,1,1],[1,0,0,4],[1,0,1,5], ...
```

And I would like to see what the origional array looks like with the brackets. I would also like to stay away from JSON.stringify(); and JSON.parse();

Comment: Question is unclear, what is the input you are providing and the output you are expecting? And why not using `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: I would do a [`BFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) function.

Comment: It seems `JSON.stringify` would provide exactly what you are looking for, being able to see what the array looks like with the brackets. Why the avoidance of `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: The input that im providing is an array composed of an image in base 64, followed by what the image is (car, number 1, computer).

Comment: I would like to be able to turn the array from the string, back into the array... and JSON.parse(); turns the string into an object instead of an array

Comment: If your array is structured correctly, `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` is literally what you're describing.

Comment: @DMVerfurth, `JSON.parse` on a stringified array will convert it back to an array (using a simple nested array with 0 in it): `Array.isArray(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([[0]])))`

Comment: I got an output of [object Object],1,[object Object],2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` will do exactly what you ask for. Try it out:

```js
var arr = [[[0,0,1],1],[[1,0,0],4],[[1,0,1],5], [[0,1,1],3],[[1,1,0],6],[[0,1,0],2]];
var str = JSON.stringify(arr);
alert(str);
var parsed = JSON.parse(str);
alert(parsed);
console.log(parsed);
```