# How do make a JSON from an array

Tags: javascript

Array:

```
myArr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Expected output:

```
newArr = "[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]"
```

I have tried:

```
myArr.toString()
String(myArr)
myArr = `${myArr}`
```

What I got by doing the above methods:

```
'1,2,3,4,5,6'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746353/javascript-convert-array-to-string-while-preserving-brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gather what you would like to achieve is more or less serialization. We could use `JSON.stringify` in JavaScript to serialize an Array.

```js
const array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];
const serializedArray = JSON.stringify(arr));
```

To deserialize the Array, `JSON.parse` could be used.

```js
const originalArray = JSON.parse(serializedArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.strinify` is what you need.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

```js
const myArr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];
const myArrString = JSON.stringify(myArr);

console.log(`Here is my string: ${myArrString}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

use  JSON.stringify(myArr);

you can find out more on below link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify